Make position of layout items adaptive in QGIS Layout to avoid empty spaces due to dynamic layout items
In the QGIS Layout manager I have a Legend item and a Label item beneath it. The Legend item only shows items inside linked maps. Therefore the legend height is different by every map I make. To avoid a lot of empty space between Legend and Label item I want the position of the Label item to be adaptive.
I think that the most favourable way to get to this is to configure somewhere that the Reference point of the Label item to be the most left-bottom point of the Legend item. In this way there is never a bit of empty space. Is there a way to make this possible? Probably with an expression or variable given to the X,Y position of the Label item in the item properties?


Check this out, it is a good start to get your request fulfilled. https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/training_manual/map_composer/dynamic_layout.html

Variables were a part of the solution but the following thread answered the question completly: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416612/dynamic-height-value-from-a-layoutitem-using-a-pyqgis-function-in-qgis

Setting the Legend item "Position and size" with a reference point at the bottom left will fix this point when the legend resize...


True, but in this case it's a must that the legend has to be at the left upper corner of the canvas. So this option, is not a option :)

Yes this solution will make the legend stay just above the text label not the text label to follow the legend resizing...
